# Missing lines when working with concurrent queueing for writing to file

Tags: c#, concurrency, queue, file-writing

I am attempting to write to a file with a concurrent queue with the logging function being called from another concurrent queue similar in structure.

I seem to be having trouble getting all the logging to appear in the file. If I were to input 700 numbers approximately 50 do not print. I believe that there may be some collision with lines being overwritten on top of one another or failing silently. This issue does not occur when I debug only when I running it live. Appreciate any help that I can get. This is where I'm at.

```
public static class logging
{
    Logging.LogToFile(LogType.Info, String.Format("Number {0}", n));

    static CallQueue MessageQueue = new CallQueue(new List<string>());        
    public static async void LogToFile(LogType type, string message)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        if (MessageQueue.NextMessage == "End")
            return;

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AppendMessage(message)));
        MessageQueue.CurrentCalls++;
        
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private static async void AppendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(FullPath,
                        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write,
                        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                {
                    byte[] MessageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + message);
                    await sourceStream.WriteAsync(MessageBytes, 0, MessageBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

class CallQueue
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<string> Messages;
    public int CurrentCalls = 0;

    public CallQueue(List<string> MessageList)
    {
        Messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(MessageList);
        NextMessage = Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Add(string account)
    {
        Messages.Enqueue(account);
    }

    public string NextMessage { get; set; }

    public string GetNextMessage()
    {
        string temp;
        Messages.TryDequeue(out temp);
        NextMessage = temp ?? "End";

        return NextMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that your `AppendMessage` is not thread safe, try using a `lock` when writing to the file.

Comment: `async void`  combined with `Task.Run` . I see problems...

Comment: Be aware that `MessageQueue.CurrentCalls++;` isn't thread-safe, use `Interlocked.Increment` for that.

Comment: `NextMessage` is definitely wrong, nothing guarantees it is processed before being overwritten.  Why do you even have the `CallQueue` class when `logging.LogToFile` directly creates the file I/O task without putting `message` into the `ConcurrentQueue` ?

Comment: What's the intention behind the `NextMessage` property? Why do you need this?

Comment: @Magnetron Thank you for the tip. I was able to get all the values printed.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're correct on that and thank you for pointing that out. Originally this was used in a separate 'concurrent queue' that was loaded at the beginning of the application not shown here. Didn't realize I was essentially not using the queue.